# I am creating a react Js application with firebase hosting . It creates a short link for webrtc everytime a button is clicked

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am creating a react Js application with firebase hosting . It creates a short link for webrtc everytime a button is clicked . But I want a file to be generated on that name and get updated to the hosting so that it can be accesible.

Comment: Hello, please share the code that you have tried and then explain the issue. Do read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The code is too long to send. I have used react-router and it worked